# How to detect right click for an item in a listview in Javascript Metro application

Tags: javascript, windows-8, windows-runtime, winjs

I'm trying to find which event is triggered when you right click an item in a listview.
When I right an item it marks it as selected but I can't seem to find which event is triggered.

I have attached a function to the oniteminvoked event, which is triggered correctly when I left-click an item but not when I right-click it.

Which event is triggered when I right-click an item?.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it's worth, you should also see a selectionchanging and selectionchanged event since the listview.selection property will be updated. This is a ListView event, not an item event, but might be useful depending on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks. I ultimately did it using selectionchanged event but it required some extra code. Basically, setting selected items programatically triggers the selectionchanged event (which seems reasonably) thus code would interpret it as a right click which isn't correct. Shouldn't it be a cleaner way of doing this?. It would be great if itemInvoked event object had the neccesary information to know with which mouse button the event was triggered.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [AppBar object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229670.aspx) to give your users a right click experience.  See [Commanding Design for Metro Style Apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/hh761499).  That said, you could listen for `contextmenu` ...

```
object.addEventListener("contextmenu", handler, useCapture)
```